# How to properly autostart an asp.net application in IIS10

Tags: asp.net, iis, autostart

I'm trying to get my ASP.NET application to automatically start whenever the application pool is running.

As per the lots and lots of references online I have already done the following:

- Set the Application Pool to `StartMode=AlwaysRunning`
- Set the site in question (that belongs to beforementioned Pool) to `preloadEnabled=true`
- Install the `Application Initialization` feature to the Windows installation
- Add the `<applicationInitialization>` node to the web.config's `<system.webServer>` node

The web application is based on Owin and has a simple log4net logging statement in it's `Startup.Configuration()` method. Now when restarting IIS I see that the w3svc.exe process is running, so I know the `StartMode=AlwaysRunning` is working. There are however no logging messages in the log file.

Navigating to any url (even a nonexisting one) in the application will start the app and add the log line.

Because of the actual work that's done in the startup of the application I really want the application to truly preload, but I seem to be unable to get it done.

Searching this site I have unfortunately not been able to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install the Web Server | Application Development | Application Initialization server feature? See http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization#TOC301259895

Comment: I did actually, and while I'm unsure what changed, it is working now. I think I just missed a required reboot or something.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To answer my own question for future generations, it seems I was on the right track. To get the application to start in IIS10 (and I assume in IIS 8 as well) you only need the following three steps:

1. Set the Application Pool to `StartMode=AlwaysRunning` to make sure the w3svc.exe process is always running for the App Pool.
2. Set the site in question (that belongs to beforementioned Pool) to `preloadEnabled=true`
3. Install the `Application Initialization` feature to the Windows installation as per the instructions [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization#TOC301259895).

One important thing to note is that if the `Application Initialization` task was not previously installed on the machine you **must reboot the machine**. This is what I missed the last time which led to quite some time wasted looking for other things :(

Anyway, setting up those three things will cause the app to actually go through it's initialization, which is especially useful if you want to setup some scheduling task (ea using the [Quartz](https://www.nuget.org/packages/quartz/) NuGet package).

Note by the way that if you setup auto initialization like above, the application will also automatically start after the shutdown timeout has expired and on application pool recycles.

Comment: You made my day. Although I didn't had to reboot the machine, iisreset was enough for me to get it working.

Comment: I would also add `Idle Time-out (minutes)` equals to 0. It's a setting of Application Pool.

Comment: Is it indeed optional to do the `<add initializationPage="">` step described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization#modifications-in-the-applications-webconfig)?

Comment: Not sure if you would still remember, but I set my application (.Net Core) to all the steps mentioned. It does restart, but Log4net, and Quartz doesn't resume. Is there something else I should be doing within the application? Is there some method called I can leverage during preload?

Comment: Another thing to note is, that you will actually get the warm up requests fired, but only AFTER the first access to the application if you forget to restart IIS/Windows. So, the first access to the application will be terribly slow, since it will not only call what you requested, but also all applicationInitialization urls. After restarting, the warm up requests will be performed immediately as expected.